# Activate virtualenvwrapper and run ssh-agent on login

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh, virtualenvwrapper

I want to activate virtualenvwrapper and start ssh-agent on start (so I can later add key using ssh-add)

Here is what I tried:

```
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
exec /usr/bin/ssh-agent $SHELL
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, because exec will cancel the effect of the source command. So I'm stuck. Every other solution I'm finding on stack overflow seems to include exec in one form or another :(.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

instead

This will allow you to start ssh-agent without spawning a new shell. In a new shell, your `source` command will be out of scope, but in the current shell, it should still apply.

Comment: Thanks! One problem with this approach is that ssh-agent won't die after ssh connection is terminated, and ssh-agents keeps piling up. Is something can be done about it?

Comment: I like `kill $(pgrep ssh-agent)` for killing processes in bash.